# Custom vscode theme extension not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make my own set of themes so I went through the process of creating a theme with `yo code` and generated a new color theme. So then in the `README.md` it says at the bottom:

```
## Install your extension

* To start using your extension with Visual Studio Code copy it into the `<user home>/.vscode/extensions` folder and restart Code.
* To share your extension with the world, read on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs about publishing an extension.
```

So I dropped it in the extensions folder located here `C:\Users\MyUsername\.vscode\extensions` and restarted vscode but nothing is showing up. I should have all of the necessary requirements. Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "custom-themes",
  "displayName": "Custom Themes",
  "description": "My custom themes",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.79.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Themes"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "themes": [
      {
        "label": "Dark Blue (Custom Theme)",
        "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
        "path": "./themes/dark-blue.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is what the folder structure looks like:

[image: Folder structure]

This should be showing up but it is like vscode is just completely ignoring this extension. If I run it with f5 it works just fine in the development environment but nothing when just trying to load it natively.

**Edit**

So I rebuilt the extension in place in the extensions folder. Then it worked fine. But now I can't edit the theme. Any edits that I make don't show up. Is there some kind of caching going on that I don't know about? There is literally nothing on their documentation about this and I can't find anything online. This should be such an easy thing to do. WTF Microsoft. I'm about to just go back to editing the theme from the settings but then if I want to change themes I have to copy and paste in new settings.

Answer (score -2):

Pressing F5 will open an additonal VS Code instance with the current theme you are developing.